# How to login a user automatically?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I want to create a "guest account" and then login the user to that account.

Creating the account on the server side is fine, and better than doing it client side!

But once this account is created, how do I login the user with it, given that my server would know the password (that it just created)

It seems there are methods to login with external services but not just with a password.

- [meteor DOCS link here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a4b33110e3595d63fbf6f6ecf3144903a4aab0ce/docs/client/full-api/api/accounts.md#accounts_createuser)
- [meteor login source code here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a4b33110e3595d63fbf6f6ecf3144903a4aab0ce/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js)

If I create the account client side, it will then login the user, but for various reasons I cannot do this. One is a [dependency on another package that bans this](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/165) but generally creating accounts client side isn't smart, even if they are throwaway guest accounts.

sankyu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doh! you just have to know what to look for! hope it helps someone else!

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword